# Enable DELETE method with nginx, passenger and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I try to deploy a rails application with passenger and nginx.
All is working fine but when i want to send a **DELETE** request like this for example:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", sign_out_path, method: :delete %>
```

In developpement it works fine but in production with nginx it's doing a **GET** request instead. So logically i get this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/sign_out")
```

I have read that nginx needs to be compiled with the [http_dav_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_dav_module.html) to be able to use the DELETE method.

I did it and added the module in nginx configuration file like so:

```
server {
  listen       8080;

  server_name  framework1.local.42.fr;
  passenger_enabled   on;

  location / {

    root          /rails/Framework00/public
    dav_methods   PUT DELETE;
    dav_access    group:rw  all:r;
  }
```

But I get the same thing, the DELETE method doesn't work.

Any idea of how I can fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you have js errors on production. JavaScript that should send DELETE request does not work.